# Vuejs sorting a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Do someone know how to sort this data?

I want to sort using 2 options! 
 
Type to be: select input 
Priority to be: 3 check radio like( 0 = Normal, 1 = Important, 2 = Urgent)

For example when i select from type input value 2 and from priority check radio 1 then all list from type 2 and with priority 1 to be in front.

Hope i explain right.

```
Lists: [
    { id: 1, priority: 1, type: 0, title: 'Whatever 1' },
    { id: 2, priority: 2, type: 3, title: 'I love cards' },
    { id: 3, priority: 0, type: 5, title: 'Movie start' },
    { id: 4, priority: 2, type: 1, title: 'Computer data' },
    { id: 5, priority: 0, type: 2, title: 'Phone style' },
    { id: 6, priority: 1, type: 5, title: 'Email received' },
],
```

And here is the code:

```
    <div>
    <!-- Start filters -->
    <div style="padding: 20px;">
        <h1>Filters</h1>
        Search: <input v-model="filterText" style="border: 1px solid;" />
        <v-col cols="3">
            <v-select
                v-model="type"
                :items="typeItems"
                item-value="id"
                item-text="name"
                label="Type"
            />
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" class="pt-1">
            <v-radio-group label="Priority" row dense v-model="priority" class="d-inline-block mt-0">
                <v-radio class="d-inline-block" color="orange" label="Normal" :value="0"></v-radio>
                <v-radio class="d-inline-block" color="green" label="Important" :value="1"></v-radio>
                <v-radio class="d-inline-block" color="red" label="Urgent" :value="2"></v-radio>
            </v-radio-group>
        </v-col>
    </div>
    <!-- End filters -->

    <!-- Start list -->
    <div v-for="(list, index) in ListFiltered" :key="list.id" :index="index">
        <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid; margin: 10px; padding: 10px;" :class="list.priority === 0 ? 'orange' : list.priority === 1 ? 'green' : 'red'">
            List id #{{ list.id }} <br />
            Priority: {{ list.priority }} <br />
            Type: {{ list.type }} <br />
            Title: {{ list.title }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End list -->
</div>

    data() {
    return {
        Lists: [
            { id: 1, priority: 1, type: 0, title: 'Whatever 1' },
            { id: 2, priority: 2, type: 3, title: 'I love cards' },
            { id: 3, priority: 0, type: 5, title: 'Movie start' },
            { id: 4, priority: 2, type: 1, title: 'Computer data' },
            { id: 5, priority: 0, type: 2, title: 'Phone style' },
            { id: 6, priority: 1, type: 5, title: 'Email received' },
        ],

        // Search filter
        filterText: '',

        // Type filter
        type: 0,
        typeItems: [
            { id: 0, name: "All" },
            { id: 2, name: "Home" },
            { id: 3, name: "Office" },
            { id: 4, name: "Computers" },
            { id: 5, name: "Movies" },
        ],

        // Priority filter
        priority: 0
    }
},
computed: {
    ListFiltered() {
        let filter = new RegExp(this.filterText, 'i')
        return this.Lists.filter(el => el.title.match(filter))
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sortByKey = (key = '',reverve = false) => (a,b) => (a[key] > b[key] ? (reverse ? -1 : 1) : (reverse ? 1:-1))
Lists.sort(sortByKey('priority'))
```

**UPD** p.s.

```
Search: <input v-model="filterText" style="border: 1px solid;" />

Here needs the input select which will be type
Here needs the check radio (0 = Normal, 1 = Important, 2 = Urgent)

<div v-for="(list, index) in ListFiltered" :key="list.id" :index="index">
        <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid; margin: 10px; padding: 10px;" :class="list.priority === 0 ? 'orange' : list.priority === 1 ? 'green' : 'red'">
            List id #{{ list.id }} <br />
            Priority: {{ list.priority }} <br />
            Type: {{ list.type }} <br />
            Title: {{ list.title }}
        </div>
    </div>

data() {
  return {
    filterText = ''
  }
}
methods:{
  sortByKey(key = '',reverve = false){
    return (a,b) => (a[key] > b[key] ? (reverse ? -1 : 1) : (reverse ? 1:-1))
  }
}
computed: {
    ListFiltered() {
        let filter = new RegExp(this.filterText, 'i')
        return this.Lists.filter(el => el.title.match(filter)).sort(this.sortByKey('priority'))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort` method for arrays, and customize it as needed, this has two parameters which are two comparing values with those you can defined the criteria for the sort, I think I got pretty close to what you need but please try to cover all the cases and modify it as needed. Here every time the property `type` or `priority` changes it sorts the table

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      lists: [{
          id: 1,
          priority: 1,
          type: 0,
          title: "Whatever 1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          priority: 2,
          type: 3,
          title: "I love cards"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          priority: 0,
          type: 5,
          title: "Movie start"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          priority: 2,
          type: 1,
          title: "Computer data"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          priority: 0,
          type: 2,
          title: "Phone style"
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          priority: 1,
          type: 5,
          title: "Email received"
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          priority: 1,
          type: 2,
          title: 'I love cards 2'
        },
      ],
      typeItems: [{
          id: 0,
          name: "All"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Home"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Office"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Computers"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Movies"
        },
      ],
      type: 2,
      priority: 1
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.sort()
  },
  methods: {
    sort() {
      this.lists.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.type === this.type && b.type === this.type) {
          if (a.priority === this.priority && b.priority === this.priority) return -1;
          else if (a.priority !== this.priority && b.priority === this.priority) return 1;
          else if (a.priority === this.priority && b.priority !== this.priority) return -1;
          else return a.priority - b.priority;
        }

        if (a.type === this.type && b.type !== this.type) return -1;
        else if (a.type !== this.type && b.type === this.type) return 1;
        else if (a.type === b.type) {
          return a.priority - b.priority;
        } else {
          return a.type - b.type;
        }
      });
    },
  },
  watch: {
    type() {
      this.sort();
    },
    priority() {
      this.sort();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Priority</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="item in lists" :key="item.id">
      <td>
        {{ item.type }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ item.priority }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ item.title }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" v-model="priority" class="d-inline-block" color="orange" label="Normal" :value="0">0</v-radio>
    <input type="radio" v-model="priority" class="d-inline-block" color="green" label="Important" :value="1">1</v-radio>
    <input type="radio" v-model="priority" class="d-inline-block" color="red" label="Urgent" :value="2">2</v-radio>
  </div>

  <select v-model="type">
    <option v-for="typeItem in typeItems" :key="typeItem.id" :value="typeItem.id">{{ typeItem.name }}</option>
  </select>

  <div>
    priority: {{ priority }}
  </div>
  <div>
    type: {{ type }}
  </div>
</div>
```